# Squashing commits far apart in git history

Tags: git, git-rebase

Say, I have 3 `git` commits `A, B` and `C`. Is it possible to `squash` `A` and `C` together while keeping `B` using `git rebase`? If yes, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that -- as long as it does not conflict (or you can fix it on conflict).

In the interactive mode (`git rebase -i`) reorder the lines to put them together and mark them as squash.

You can reorder / take away any commits using the same method.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of reordering the lines.