# How to squash/fixup commits very far apart? Non-interactive rebase

Tags: git

Let's say I have commit 1, 2 ... 10.000.000, and I want to fixup commit 8.000.000 to 1.000, e.g sha2 is merged into sha1, keeping sha1's commit message, and keeping all other commits in order, where sha1 and sha2 are *very* far from each other and *very* far from HEAD.

This question has been asked several times, but every time it is assumed that the commits are close to each other and close to HEAD and `git rebase -i HEAD~5` can be used. I just don't see how that is manageable as the number of commits scale.

I am hoping for an answer along the lines of `git rebase --fixup sha2 --onto sha1`

Related questions:

- [Squashing commits far apart in git history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143414/squashing-commits-far-apart-in-git-history) despite title, question and answer assumes commits are close to each other and close to HEAD.
- [how to re-order commits in Git non-interactively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981061/how-to-re-order-commits-in-git-non-interactively) asks to reorder non-interactively, but top answers uses interactive rebase, and other answer suggest writing a line for each commit between sha1 and sha2
- [How do I run git rebase --interactive in non-interactive manner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394166/how-do-i-run-git-rebase-interactive-in-non-interactive-manner) asks about how to export rebase list to a file for later editing.
- [Squash Git commits *non-interactively* with git rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42332906/squash-git-commits-non-interactively-with-git-rebase) wants to squash all commits not shared between two branches. I want to squash/fixup 1 commit into 1 other commit, keeping all other commits the same.

Comment: Do I understand correctly: you want to squash the 8,000,000th commit into the 1,000th commit and keep the commit message of the 1,000th commit? (I am also assuming that 1 is the oldest commit and 10,000,000 is the youngest---most recent---commit.)

Comment: Yes. 1 is the oldest commit, and 10.000.000 is the newest. I want to squash (or fixup) 8,000,000th into the 1,000th

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following solution.

```
git checkout <COMMIT_HASH YOU WANT TO BE SQUASHED>
git reset --soft HEAD~1
git stash
```

This will stash changes of commit you want to squash. Then:

```
git checkout master
git rebase -i <BASE COMMIT HASH -1>
```

In the opened editor

```
edit <COMMIT HASH YOU WANT TO MAKE BASIC>
...
drop <COMMIT HASH YOU WANT TO SQUASH>
```

After rebase process stops on the commit you marked as "edit", then:

```
git stash pop
git add -A
git commit
git rebase --continue
```

Comment: `git rebase -i <BASE COMMIT HASH -1>` won't this open a file with just under 8 million lines as there are millions of commits between sha1 and sha2?

Comment: Yes, indeed, it will cause this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You use `git rebase -i` and reorder the lines and mark the one you want to squash into the earlier one with `fixup`. Yes, this opens a file with millions of lines.

Instead of doing it interactively, you can set `sequence.editor` to a script that modifies the lines, for example:

```
git -c sequence.editor='f () {
   sed -i -e '1000a fixup abcde12345' -e '8000000d' "$1"
   }; f' rebase -i basecommit
```

Here, `abcde12345` is the commit ID of the 8,000,000th commit.

If you do not want to depend on counts, but use commit IDs instead, you can do:

```
git -c sequence.editor='f () {
   sed -i -e '/pick 54ab32/a fixup abcde12345' -e '/pick abcde123/d' "$1"
   }; f' rebase -i basecommit
```

Note that the IDs after `/pick` must be given no longer than they appear in the file (typically only 6 characters, but probably more in your case where you have millions of objects).